# How to represent range of time as bits

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am using bitwise operation to store availability with 1 bit representing one minutes. So one day of availability can be represented by 1 long (8 bytes so 60 bits out of 64 bits) can be used to represent 1 hour so 24 longs will represent availability per day.

Now I have a range of times (ex. 2:00 - 4:00, 15:00 to 17:00) and I need to translate this into bit mask to compare against above longs of availabilities to see if the ranges in the mask is available or unavailable (& with mask) what is the best way to translate this range of times to bits?

Comment: If one bit is one minute, one day of availability would be 1440 bits or 180 bytes.

Comment: Yes I know. long data type is 64 bits so I can use 1 long (60 bits out of 64 assuming long is 8 bytes) to hold availability for one hour * 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this works:

```
private static int getMinuteOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

    cal.setTime(date);

    return cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) * 60 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}

private static void addAvailability(Date startTime, Date endTime, BitSet bs) {

    int startMinute = getMinuteOfDay(startTime);
    int endMinute = getMinuteOfDay(endTime);

    bs.set(startMinute, endMinute);
}

private static boolean timeIsAvailable(Date time, BitSet bs) {
    return bs.get(getMinuteOfDay(time));
}

static DateFormat TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BitSet availability = new BitSet();

    try {
        addAvailability(TIME_FORMAT.parse("02:00:00"), TIME_FORMAT.parse("04:00:00"), availability);
        addAvailability(TIME_FORMAT.parse("15:00:00"), TIME_FORMAT.parse("17:00:00"), availability);

        System.out.println(timeIsAvailable(TIME_FORMAT.parse("01:19:00"), availability));
        System.out.println(timeIsAvailable(TIME_FORMAT.parse("02:00:00"), availability));
        System.out.println(timeIsAvailable(TIME_FORMAT.parse("02:01:00"), availability));
        System.out.println(timeIsAvailable(TIME_FORMAT.parse("04:00:00"), availability));
        System.out.println(timeIsAvailable(TIME_FORMAT.parse("04:01:00"), availability));
        System.out.println(timeIsAvailable(TIME_FORMAT.parse("16:00:00"), availability));
        System.out.println(timeIsAvailable(TIME_FORMAT.parse("17:10:00"), availability));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Results:

```
false
true
true
false
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce a problem to simpler steps:

1. convert an interval (start_minute,end_minute) into bitmask. This can be done as follows:
   1a: Iterate on the 24 longs.
   1b: If start_minute is less than 60 convert it into long. The same for end_minute.
   1c: Compose the bitmask adding bits from 1<
2. to represent a sequence of intervals make an "or" of their bitmasks